# wicket use-case: form with some positive feedback, e.g. forgot-password-request

Tags: wicket, forms

What is the best practice to do a form with wicket that results in some positive feedback message?

Example: I have a form where the user can request a link to change his forgotten password. The user gets this link sent to his given email address (as usual).

If the user enters his (valid) email address in the form and presses the submit button, I would like to show a positive feedback message like: "A mail to change your password will be sent to your mail address".

I see the following options to do this:

- Using the feedback panel for this message (as 'info'), but using the feedback panel of the form, the form is still there (and maybe active) and that is not so nice ...
- Redirecting to a page that does show nothing else than this message. A new page just for this message is not very 'wicket-like', is it?
- Using a modal window. (But this does not fit to my design in this case.)

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 3):

It is about your design vision, not about wicket, I think.

1) In our apps we usually use modal window for "password restore" form, and when user submits this form, then modal window is closing and javascript div appears (like another window, but with static) called via ajax. I.e. we have such div on our base page html:

```html
<div class="message-dialog" id="dialog_window">
    <p id="dialog_window_p">[MESSAGE HERE]</p>
    <a class="w_close"></a>
</div>
```

Some javascript functions:

```jquery
    //function to show div as window.
    function showNotification(message) {
        var msg = message;
        $("#dialog_window_p").html('<span>' + msg + '</span>');
        $('#dialog_window a.w_close').show();
        $("#dialog_window").fadeIn(300);
    }

    //set listener to close link. may be you could use plain onclick="..", can't remember why we done so.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog_window a.w_close").click( function(){
            $("#dialog_window").fadeOut(300);
        });
    });
```

And style:

```css
.message-dialog {
    display:none;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

May be this is a little clumsy, but I'm not strong in js and css. Also you can set some variable, for example `passwordRestored = true` in your session and redirect to home page after submition. When home page is creating you check this var and if it is `true` - show this popup and set this var back to `false`.

2) Many sites redirect users after their submits to another page, so this approach is viable, but you could also use AJAX just to hide form and show hidden span with success message (or feedback panel). To use AJAX you must replace you submit `Button` with 'AjaxButton' which requires to override onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) method. In this method you could do something like that:

```java
 onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if (submitionCorrect)
    {
        form.setVisible(false);
        successLabel.setVisible (true);
        target.add (form, successLabel);        
    } else {...}
 }
```

And don't forget to set `form` and `successLabel` `.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag (true)`.

3) If you don't want to use one of this approach - I see only way to ask user for a phone number at your form and send him sms after submit :D

Comment: I use a similar approach :)